# I got this error: definition of implicitly-declared

Tags: c++

I am just a beginner at c++ so I just wanted to make a simple program.
but I have ran in a lot of trouble making this.
please tell me how to fix this error as I don't know much about constructors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
MessageBox(NULL,"YOU HAVE BEEN PROMOTED TO TEST THIS CONSOLE APP FOR FREE!!","PROMOTION!!",NULL);
cout << "Hello world!............ first do you want this program to changeyour files  to save progress??" << endl;
int save;
cout << "press 1 to allow press 2 to deny!!"<<endl;
cin >> save;
if(save == 1){

ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("data.txt");
}
if(save == 2 );


cout<<"set up done!!!"<<endl;


return 0;
}
```

and this is my Boss class

```
#ifndef BOSS_H
#define BOSS_H


class Boss
{

    int boss_helth(){
        int boss_helth0 = 200;
        return boss_helth();

    }
 void Punch(){



 }


};
```

and last of all my player class

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H


class Player
{

 int Player_helth(){
 Player_helth0 = 200;
 return player_helth0;

 }
 void patt(){
public:

    int power_punch = - 20;

 }





};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

I don't know why I am getting this error.

```
`
```

Comment: Ummmmm... What error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the error is that when you're trying to declare variable Player_helth0, you're not indicating a type. It should be:

```
int Player_helth0 = 200;
```

I see another (unrelated) problem too. In Boss_helth your return value should be the variable Boss_helth0, but you're returning a call to the function instead.

Comment: @Aaron Hill, the "implicitly declared" in your question title gave me a hint, but you should really add the error to the body of the question, and include the entire error message. That way it'll be easier to understand the question... and to get help.

Comment: It reads: definition of implicitly  declared 'Boss::Boss()'.